# Use data from datasets

Tags: vega

I am trying to use data from datasets. Here the vega config spec :

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "datasets": {
    "data_2": [
      {"category": "A", "sex": 1, "people": 1483789},
      {"category": "B", "sex": 2, "people": 1450376},
      {"category": "C", "sex": 1, "people": 2411067}
    ],
    "data_1": [
      {"a": "A", "b": 28},
      {"a": "B", "b": 55},
      {"a": "C", "b": 43}
    ]
  },
  "concat": [
    {
      "data": {"name": "data_1"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "a"},
        "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "b"}
      },
      "mark": "bar"
    },
    {
      "data": {"name": "data_2"},
      "encoding": {
        "color": {"field": "sex"},
        "x": {"title": "population", "field": "category", "sort": "color"},
        "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "people"}
      },
      "mark": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

It seems that VEGA doesn't find the reference name to the data. data_1 or data_2

Tested in VEGA editor it returns the following message :  Duplicate data set name: "data_1"

All advice is welcome

Erwan

Comment: An idea from a vega-lite superhero :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely not a vega-lite superhero. But vega-lite compiles to vega.

You can see what it makes of it in the online editor. At the bottom you can see: **compile to Vega**. And then you can open that Vega in the online editor. And then you can see it does something with datasets, where it uses the name `data_1` for something else.
So I think there is nothing wrong with your vega-lite code, just rename datasets `data_1` and `data_2` to something else, and it will be fine.